# Android: Having custom buttons with an image while text aligned to the right and left

Tags: android, user-interface, button, imageview, drawable

I have an imageView in which I using an OnClickListener, this way I have a custom button.

I also have text next to the imageView, however I want them to be able to click near the text as well.

I was wondering if it's possible to create a drawable file and just have the one button.

Here is what I have so far:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BeR5.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a regular button.
Set the images using `drawableLeft` and `drawableRight` attributes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/backButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_chevron_left_white_24dp"
        android:text="Back" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/nextButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_chevron_right_white_24dp"
        android:text="Next" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

You can also set `android:background="@null"` to remove the button outline and show only the text and the icon.  It will look closer to your screen shot and the user can click on the icon or the text and the button will get the click.

Comment: Okay, so the image works. Although the background "@null" was invalid, so instead I used the transparent colour. Now for some reason, the image is too far to the left and also the text doesn't appear.

I did set the height and width to 50dp each.

[link](http://i.imgur.com/rB2oxgt.png)

Comment: Also by setting the width to "wrap_content". The image becomes very large. Also the text is very far away from the actual image. Also I managed to shift the button closer to the edge by setting the padding to -15dp for each button. Although still, the image is very large.

Comment: What are the dimensions on your icons?  I pulled the icons from Google's Material Design Icon library https://design.google.com/icons/ and my icons are 24dp, they look about the same height as my text.  Are you using smaller text?  I am using the default AppTheme style.

Comment: Ahhh, I downloaded the 48dp. I'll try switching them for the 24dp.

Answer (score 0):

Create a CustomView:

```
package com.android4dev.navigationview;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.ImageView;

/**
 * Created by 77930 on 2016/1/24.
 */
public class MyView extends ImageView {
    public interface OnAreaClickListener{
        public void onLeftClick(MyView view);
        public void onRightClick(MyView view);
    }

    public OnAreaClickListener listener;

    public OnAreaClickListener getListener() {
        return listener;
    }

    public void setListener(OnAreaClickListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            if(event.getX() < getWidth()/3){
                if(listener!=null) listener.onLeftClick(MyView.this);
            }else if(event.getX() > getWidth()/3){
                if(listener!=null) listener.onRightClick(MyView.this);
            }
        }

        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

Add in layout:

```
    <com.android4dev.navigationview.MyView
        android:id="@+id/btn_all"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Bind Click:

```
    MyView myView = (MyView)findViewById(R.id.btn_all);
    myView.setListener(new MyView.OnAreaClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLeftClick(MyView view) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onRightClick(MyView view) {

        }
    });
```